# How to add a primary key to a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

This is what I tried but it fails:

```
alter table goods add column `id` int(10) unsigned primary AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Does anyone have a tip?

Comment: When something *fails*, it's always a good idea to specify what *fails* means : do you get an error message ? which one ?

Comment: I guess error message looks like : multiple primarys key defined

Comment: Just a typo: primary *key*.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

After adding the column, you can always add the primary key:

`ALTER TABLE goods ADD PRIMARY KEY(id)`

As to why your script wasn't working, you need to specify `PRIMARY KEY`, not just the word `PRIMARY`:

```
alter table goods add column `id` int(10) unsigned primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: For me it says : this would define multiple primary keys. Im using InnoDB. Note I already have 3 of them.

Comment: I would definitely put `FIRST` after `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which means, that the `id` will be first column of the already existing table. Otherwise it will be put at the end of the table as it is written now, which can be a little confusing when doing simple `SELECT * ...`

Comment: How to get a first place to new 'id' column

Comment: I don't think you need the `(10)` around int. And add `FIRST` to the end so the primary key is the first column in the table

Answer (score 30):

### Existing Column

If you want to add a primary key constraint to an existing column all of the previously listed syntax will fail.

To add a primary key constraint to an existing column use the form:

```
ALTER TABLE `goods`
MODIFY COLUMN `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

NOTE: Apparently with some versions of MYSQL you must replace MODIFY with CHANGE
(Thanks @csr-nontol !)

Comment: mysql doesn't recognize MODIFY as proper statement(at least in XAMPP, InnoDB)

Comment: @LMD What version of mysql are you on? (NOTE: I know it worked at the time I posted this and I believe it was 5.6... but I can't remember for sure)

Comment: If to you, like for me, it does not work replace MODIFY with CHANGE and it will work!

Answer (score 16):

If your table is quite big better not use the statement:

```
alter table goods add column `id` int(10) unsigned primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

because it makes a copy of all data in a temporary table, alter table and then copies it back.
Better do it manually. 
Rename your table:

```
rename table goods to goods_old;
```

create new table with primary key and all necessary indexes:

```
create table goods (
    id  int(10) unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT
    ... other columns ...
    primary key (id)
);
```

move all data from the old table into new, disabling keys and indexes to speed up copying:

-- USE THIS FOR [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) TABLES:

```
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
    ALTER TABLE goods DISABLE KEYS;
        INSERT INTO goods (... your column names ...) SELECT ... your column names FROM goods_old; 
    ALTER TABLE goods ENABLE KEYS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1;
```

#### OR

-- USE THIS FOR [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) TABLES:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    INSERT INTO goods (... your column names ...) SELECT ... your column names FROM goods_old; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1; COMMIT; SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1;
```

It takes 2 000 seconds to add PK to a table with ~200 mln rows.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this matters to anyone else, but I prefer the id for the table to be the first column in the database. The syntax for that is:

```
ALTER TABLE your_db.your_table ADD COLUMN `id` int(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Which is just a slight improvement over the first answer. If you wanted it to be in a different position, then

```
ALTER TABLE unique_address ADD COLUMN `id` int(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER some_other_column;
```

HTH,
-ft

Answer (score 7):

Use this query,

```
alter table `table_name` add primary key(`column_name`);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code work in my mysql db:

```
ALTER TABLE `goods`
ADD COLUMN `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of suggestions worked giving me the errors of syntax, so I just gave a try using phpmyadmin(version 4.9.2), (10.4.10-MariaDB) and added `id` column with auto-increment primary key. `Id` column was nicely added from the first element.

Query output was:

ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE GOODS MODIFY ID INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 1):

If previously you already have one or more primary keys and you want to include more column as primary key, you need to add `DROP PRIMARY KEY` in your statement and re-mention previous keys along with new ones in `ADD PRIMARY KEY` section. Take a look at the following example..

Previously, `my_test_table` had only a single primary key column named `old_key`. Then we add a new column named `new_key`.

```
ALTER TABLE my_test_table ADD COLUMN new_key INT; -- Or whatever data type you need
```

If we want to make our table to have primary key set `{old_key, new_key}`, then the following statement can be used:

```
ALTER TABLE my_test_table
DROP PRIMARY KEY, -- You have to add this
ADD PRIMARY KEY(
    old_key,      -- Re-mention the old key
    new_key       -- And mention also the new one
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
alter table goods add column `id` int(10) unsigned primary key auto_increment
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `goods`
MODIFY COLUMN `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score -3):

Remove  quotes to work properly...

```
alter table goods add column id int(10) unsigned primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```