# CakePHP - Display another list record inside in listed record

Tags: php, cakephp, html-table, record

`How` can we `display` another list record `inside` in listed record using CakePHP?

I have 3 table that consist: (staff,course,attendance)

(Staff)

```
staff_id    |   name    |   passport
------------------------------------------------
1       |   A   |   123
2       |   B   |   132
3       |   C   |   321
```

(Course)

```
c_id    |   name
----------------------
10  |   PHP
20  |   AJAX
30  |   XHTML
```

(Attendance)

```
at_id   |   staff_id    |   course_id
------------------------------------------------
1   |   1       |   10
2   |   1       |   20
3   |   1       |   30
4   |   2       |   20
5   |   2       |   30
```

I would like to generate some report to display listed of course that attend by our staff as you can see below:

```
Name    |   Course Attend
------------------------------
A   |   PHP
    |   AJAX
    |   XHTML
B   |   AJAX
    |   XHTML
```

Here I use table staff in displaying result and what should I do to get some another fetch result in my column `Course Attend` that related to attendance table which will be listed all the related result to their staff ids.

My Code:

(ReportController.php)

```
$view = $this->Staff->find('all');

$this->set('view', $view);
```

(View - report.ctp)

```
<table>
<?php foreach($view as $data): ?>
<td>
    <?php echo $data['Staff']['name']; ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php // something to do here... ?>
</td>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does your `view` variable look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear from your question, but it seems to me like you want to display a view that contains information from all the 3 tables.

In this case, you will need to create [Model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

In the **Attendance model:**

```
class Attendance extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array(
        'Staff' => array(
            'className'  => 'Staff',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Staff.staff_id = Attendance.staff_id')
        ),
        'Course' => array(
            'className'  => 'Course',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Course.c_id = Attendance.course_id')
        )
    );
}
```

In the **controller**, you can add a find('all') query that will retrieve all the rows from Attendance, together with their corresponding Staff and Course rows.

```
$attendance_rows = $this->Attendance->find('all', array('order' => 'Staff.name ASC, Staff.staff_id ASC'));
$this->set("attendance_rows", $attendance_rows);
```

In the **view**, you can use a foreach loop as usual:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($attendance_rows as $data): ?>
<td>
    <?php echo $data['Staff']['name']; ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $data['Course']['name']; ?>
</td>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

To display the names of the Staff only once, you can add a variable in the view and reset it each time a new Staff row is found. This works if the find('all') query is ordered.

```
<table>
<?php $temp = null; $no = 1;?>
<?php foreach($attendance_rows as $data): ?>
<td>
    <?php if ($temp != $data['Staff']['staff_id']) { echo $no; $no++;} ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php if ($temp != $data['Staff']['staff_id']) { echo $data['Staff']['name']; $temp = $data['Staff']['staff_id']}; ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $data['Course']['name']; ?>
</td>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

One more suggestion: you should always name your primary keys as 'id', not 'staff_id' or 'c_id', since Cakephp knows how to bind models based on their names. If you create the models 'the Cakephp way', you won't need to specify the 'foreignKey' or 'conditions' fields when creating associations.

Comment: i just use this code: public `$belongsTo = array('Staff','Course');` in attendance model...need to try it..i will post a result soon..thanks a lot @alex.ac

Comment: just try it, pretty good implement at model ..but how could we generate some numbers because some of same data in a row also be counter

Comment: What do you mean by generate some numbers? Do you want the staff, courses and attendance to have unique ids?

Comment: i mean that we put numbers in each row (#), 

`#|  Name    |   Course Attend
------------------------------
1 A   |   PHP
         AJAX
         XHTML
2 B   |  AJAX
         XHTML`

any solution using function to call each data from view like that:

`<table>
<?php foreach($view as $data): ?>
<td>
    <?php echo $data['Staff']['name']; ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php getDatafromDB($data['Staff']['staff_id'];) ?>
</td>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>`

Comment: I believe the numbers you are referring to are the ids or primary keys. They are generated directly from Mysql if you change the column type to Primary Key with AUTO INCREMENT.

Comment: You can take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132923/how-to-add-a-primary-key-to-a-mysql-table

Comment: i just need to make numbering like example here http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/5663/2811.png

Comment: I understand now, I modified the view example above to include the numbers.

Comment: greats, thax a lot @alex.ac