# #1005 - Can't create table 'hms.doctor' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I am getting the above error when I execute the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE doctor 
(
  id varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  Specialization varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES employee(id)
  on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You're not including `<br>` in the actual query, are you?

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on `employee(id)` and  before you add any FK pointing at it. You also need one on `doctor(id)`. In both cases, a primary key seems like a good option.

Don't forget that in the `CREATE TABLE` script, the `PRIMARY KEY` should appear before the `FOREIGN KEY` instruction.

See this post for a quick how-to: [How to add a primary key to a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5132923/1291428)

Comment: Or possibly, the data types of `doctor.id, employee.id` do not match. Can't say for certain without seeing `CREATE TABLE employee (...)`

Comment: well `id` seems like it is a primary key, so I guess you could add one to that table.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski the datatypes of doctor.id, employee.id are same

Comment: ...Must be _exactly the same_, same length, since we still don't see the other table to verify. Also the other table must exist before you attempt to create this one.