# Two ManyToMany relationships in one JPA entity

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have an entity called User with two many-to-many relationships:  **User -mtm - Role** and **User -mtm - Course**

```
public class User {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Role> userRoles;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_courses",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Course> orderedCourses;
}
```

In Course entity:

```
public class Course  {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orderedCourses")
    private List<User> participants;

}
```

It looks similar in the `Role` entity.

When user with e.g. two roles assigned enrolls himself to some course (means that course is added to his `orderedCourses` list), he gets this course twice. 
So the user with two roles gets registered for the same course twice, user with 3 roles gets it three times etc.

It is noticeable in the junction table in the database. (one user has the same course few times which is unacceptable).

Looks like one `ManyToMany` relationship has an impact on another. But I don't know what is wrong.
Everything is persisted to MySQL database by Hibernate (via Spring Data JPA)

Comment: 1. where is the code reproducing that problem? 2. Why isn't there a primary key constraint in the join table that would make this situation impossible in the first place?

Comment: 1. Well, I've noticed those ManyToMany relationships cause the problem.
2. Could you be more precise and give some hint how to implement that?

Comment: 1. That still doesn't tell me what your code is. There is a 0.001% chance that it is a Hibernate bug, and I have access to the Hibernate code. There is a 99.999% chance that it is a bug in your code, but I have no idea what it is. 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132923/how-to-add-a-primary-key-to-a-mysql-table

Comment: 1. I save entities using .save() method from CRUD repository (both for Course and User). I used many combinations and noticed that there is some improper depedence between thoese two ManyToMany relationships.
2. I use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create; this is production environment, can I achieve the same effect using just hibernate, not MySQL?

Comment: @user3541916 Please, add code,  which shows how do you save it exactly, to your question. I test your mapping and everything is correct ( I use `Set` or lazy because of "multiple bags" exception using `Session`)

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** the duplicate records actually exist in the database and not only in the model once you have reloaded an entity. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995080/hibernate-criteria-returns-children-multiple-times-with-fetchtype-eager

Comment: @AlanHay Yes, I'm sure. I see those records in MySQL join table, there are repeated records.

Comment: I changed `List` to `Set` and now it is fine. I think `Set` is more desirable than `List`, but is it a real solution? It still doesn't clarify why te Course has been added many times.

Should I add some code? I have a service with method that assigns Courses to User and then this method is called in Spring controller (data sent via POST). In the same controller I add some example data (courses, roles, users) in `@PostConstruct ` method. So should I paste only service method which is responsible for assigning courses to users, or everything?