# Field 'id' doesn't have a default value. AbstractPersistable problem

Tags: sql, spring, database, hibernate

I'm crating webservice with connection to db. I have met one problem. In my User class i used AbstractPersistable to generate primary keys but it seems to have some problem with that task.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;

@Entity
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long>{

    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

It throws me something like that:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-05-27 14:22:09.345  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] com.webservice.Application               : Starting Application on DESKTOP-7IMDU22 with PID 15080 (C:\Users\Daniel\eclipse-workspace\MyWebService\target\classes started by Daniel in C:\Users\Daniel\eclipse-workspace\MyWebService)
2020-05-27 14:22:09.348  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] com.webservice.Application               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-27 14:22:09.405  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-05-27 14:22:09.405  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-05-27 14:22:10.477  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-05-27 14:22:10.502  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-27 14:22:11.549  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2020-05-27 14:22:11.560  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-27 14:22:11.560  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-05-27 14:22:11.684  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/springboot]    : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-27 14:22:11.684  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2279 ms
2020-05-27 14:22:12.050  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-27 14:22:12.102  INFO 15080 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-27 14:22:12.137  WARN 15080 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-05-27 14:22:12.170  INFO 15080 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-05-27 14:22:12.358  INFO 15080 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-27 14:22:12.490  INFO 15080 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-27 14:22:12.741  INFO 15080 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-27 14:22:12.758  INFO 15080 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2020-05-27 14:22:13.435  INFO 15080 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-27 14:22:13.442  INFO 15080 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-27 14:22:13.462  INFO 15080 --- [         task-2] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Daniel/eclipse-workspace/MyWebService/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into `User`(`user_id`,`user_name`,`password`) values ('user id 1', 'name 1' , 'pass1'), ('user id 2', 'name 2' , 'pass2'); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:622)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:38)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:601)
    ... 17 more
2020-05-27 14:22:13.531  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-05-27 14:22:13.582  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path '/springboot'
2020-05-27 14:22:13.583  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-05-27 14:22:13.584  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-05-27 14:22:13.597  INFO 15080 --- [  restartedMain] com.webservice.Application               : Started Application in 4.64 seconds (JVM running for 5.221)
```

It must generate primary keys but they dont have default value.

Here is my data.sql file:

```
use springboot;
insert into `User`(`user_id`,`user_name`,`password`) values
('user id 1', 'name 1' , 'pass1'),
('user id 2', 'name 2' , 'pass2');
```

And aplication properties

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/springboot
server.port=9090
menagement.security.enabled=false

#Hibernate
spring.datasource.data=classpath*:data.sql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always 

#Jpa
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Can you see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804514/hibernate-field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132923/how-to-add-a-primary-key-to-a-mysql-table

Comment: I already read that and use auto increment command on id column in db. It worked but the first record was good but the second has 21312412 id and it generates 4 more record copy of that two with same huge ids

Comment: its random once it generates 2 records once 4 but always with random id

Comment: And it always place name 2 on first place

Comment: How many times did you run the code? The data.sql is executed everytime you run the application

Answer (score 0):

The following changes worked for me:

**Application.properties file:**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity

public class User { // extends AbstractPersistable<Long>

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    ..
}
```